# Phonegap: preventing youtube videos from playing in after power button is pressed?

Tags: android, cordova, youtube

I have created an app using Phonegap Build.

The app includes a few HTML pages that have youtube iframed videos on them.

After submitting my .APK to Google play store, it was rejected because it's: 'enabling background play of YouTube videos'

I have scoured stackoverflow for an answer. Many people ask similar questions but no clear answer for phonegap build ever gets provided.

The youtube video correctly stops playing when you hit the home button to navigate away from the app.

The part that I believe google approvers are having an issue with is when you press the POWER button on the phone, the screen goes dark, but the video keeps playing.

How do I prevent this?

The onPause event does not seem to fire when the power button is pressed.

Things I have tried with no success:

added to config.xml. properly closes app when home button is pressed but not when power button is pressed:

```
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="false" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
```

--

added to main app JS. no effect:

```
function pause (argument) {
  console.log("pausing all videos");
  $('#themaincontent').html("");
}
document.addEventListener("pause", pause, false);
```

--

causes app to crash:

```
function pause (argument) {
  console.log("pausing all videos");
  window.location='about:blank';
}
document.addEventListener("pause", pause, false);
```

Comment: Take a look at... [How to pause a YouTube Video Dynamically](https://css-tricks.com/play-button-youtube-and-vimeo-api/)

Comment: Use that in combination with the pause event you're using and you'll be good! (idk why but it doesnt work on PhoneGap Desktop, but it works on PhoneGap Build) - http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause